# Why does running a containerized app with AWS Lightsail cost twice as much as using a virtual server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, vps, containers, amazon-lightsail

As per https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/ , running a lightsail VPS with 512 MB Memory, 1 Core Processor costs $3.50 a month.

However, in that same link it shows that the lowest cost of containerized app on the service is twice as much at $7.00 a month with vCPU: 0.25 (shared) and RAM: 512MB

I'm not sure if these specs are directly comparable but it even seems like you get less processing power with this configuration as well.

So why wouldn't I just use the first option and setup docker in the VPS and run my containerized app that way? Amazon does just that in one of their own tutorials https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-pocket-platform-as-a-service-with-amazon-lightsail/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Lightsail is the AWS consumer oriented service, priced to compete with Digital Ocean and such. It is a *lot* cheaper than EC2 or containers especially when you take bandwidth into account.

The reason... because AWS wants it to be that way. Maybe AWS want to lure people in with a good price then have them switch to a more fully featured, more expensive service.